# Data model for nested object in Retrofit/GSON

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I'm using a remote weather API and got the following data from it. I'm making calls with Retrofit and I use GSON.

```
{"coord":{"lon":127.08,"lat":37.51},"weather":[{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50n"},
{"id":721,"main":"Haze","description":"haze","icon":"50n"}],"base":"stations",
"main":{"temp":18,"pressure":1013,"humidity":82,"temp_min":17,"temp_max":19},
"visibility":9000,"wind":{"speed":1.5,"deg":160},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1559762819,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":8096,"message":0.0054,"country":"KR","sunrise":1559765465,
"sunset":1559818179},"timezone":32400,"id":1837217,"name":"Sinch’ŏn-dong","cod":200}
```

I have a single data model named **Weather**. If I want my data model to also support **wind** do I have to create a separate data model for it because it's nested in the JSON response which I showed above?

Comment: As i can see its nested json , you need to create a different data model for wind , in order to get its value.

Comment: You should have mentioned if the language is Java or Kotlin for sample, but you will need another data model which can be an inner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you get is an object that holds both **Weather** and **Wind** let us call it `WeatherResponse`. Simplified JSON is like:

```
{
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 701,
      "main": "Mist",
      "description": "mist",
      "icon": "50n"
    },
    {
      "id": 721,
      "main": "Haze",
      "description": "haze",
      "icon": "50n"
    }
  ],
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1.5,
    "deg": 160
  }
}
```

You might have something like this in your Retrofit API:

```
@GET("weather")
Call<WeatherResponse> getWeather();
```

where `WeatherResponse` looks like:

```
public class WeatherResponse {
    public Collection<Weather> weather;
    public Wind wind; // You need to add & implement this!
}
```

If you already can parse your `Weather` it should look like:

```
public class Weather {
    public Long id;
    public String main;
    public String description;
    public String icon;
}
```

and you need to implement the class `Wind` like:

```
public class Wind {
    public Double speed;
    public Integer deg;
```

}

(*I have declared all the fields public just to shorten the code so omitting getters & setters.*)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this by creating one model class for each object and place them as a variable in outer class. However, it is time consuming

**Suggestions**

1. Search internet `json to java/kotlin` they will convert for you
2. Android Studio has many plugins to do same job. Just install one with higher starred then, this plugins will take care of creating your pojo class from given json input

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to create a new data model. And be careful with handling possible null vales. Here is a kotlin example
And, personally. I prefer to do the model manually instead of using a tool, by doing it by yourself you can realize of many things, like naming, possible null values and not needed data

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class AdReplyRequest(@SerializedName("cc_sender") val cc_sender: Boolean,
                          @SerializedName("message") val message: AdReplyMessage)

data class AdReplyMessage(@SerializedName("body") val message: String,
                          @SerializedName("email") val email: String,
                          @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
                          @SerializedName("phone") val phone: String)
```